# Dynamic content being cached

Tags: php, mysql

I've found on several pages of my site that content retrieved from the database appears to be being cached.

Example:
I have a page which uses the following query

```
SELECT c.ID, c.name FROM member_coupons AS m LEFT JOIN coupons as c on c.ID = m.couponID WHERE m.userID = 'ANONYMOUS' ORDER BY c.ID
```

If I run the query in phpMyAdmin, I get the expected results

[image]

On the website it is correct as well.

[image]

I then fill out the form on the same page, selecting anything on the drop downs and submit. This brings you to a confirmation screen, with a link back to the original screen.

PhpMyAdmin shows me the expected results.

[image]

But the website is still showing both options until I refresh

[image] - before refresh

[image]

The javascript that is called by the page on the submit is:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
            var text = "&coupon=" + $("#coupons").val();
            var text = text + "&card1=" + $("#card1").val();
            var text = text + "&card2=" + $("#card2").val();
            var text = text + "&card3=" + $("#card3").val();
            var text = text + "&card4=" + $("#card4").val();

            $.get("ajax.php?action=couponSwap" + text, function(data, status) {
                $('#content').html(data);
            });
        });
```

and the associated function

```
    function couponSwap($pdo, $get, $user) {
  $coupon = $get['coupon'];

  switch($coupon) {
    case "1RNORMAL":
      $cards[] = $user->addRandomCard(1, 'normal');
      break;
    case "2RNORMAL":
      $cards[] = $user->addRandomCard(2, 'normal');
      break;
    case "1RSPECIAL":
      $cards[] = $user->addRandomCard(1, 'special');
      break;
    case "2RSPECIAL":
      $cards[] = $user->addRandomCard(2, 'special');
      break;
    case "1CNORMAL":
      $cards[][] = $user->addCard($get['card1']);
      break;
    case "2CNORMAL":
      $cards[][] = $user->addCard($get['card1']);
      $cards[][] = $user->addCard($get['card2']);
      break;
    case "1CSPECIAL":
      $cards[][] = $user->addCard($get['card3']);
      break;
    case "2CSPECIAL":
      $cards[][] = $user->addCard($get['card3']);
      $cards[][] = $user->addCard($get['card4']);
      break;
  }

  if( count( $cards ) > 0 ){

    foreach ($cards as $cardArray) {
      foreach ($cardArray as $card) {
        echo '<img src="'.$card["card"]->showImage().'" alt="'.$card["card"]->getName().'"/> ';
        $names[] = $card["card"]->getName();
        $insertIDs[] = $card['ID'];
      }
    }
    $names = (isset($names)) ? implode(", " , $names) : 'ERROR';
    $user->addLog(date("Y-m-d"), "Coupon Swap: " . $names, $insertIDs);
  }

  $sql = "DELETE FROM member_coupons WHERE couponID = :couponID AND userID = :userID LIMIT 1";
  $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->bindValue(':couponID', $coupon);
    $q->bindValue(':userID', $user->getID());
  $q->execute();

  echo '<p><a href="game-coupon.php">Swap more coupons</a></p>';
}
```

Also seeing issues where the site is thinking a user is logged out even when they are logged in.

Cookies are set using

```
$expire = time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
setcookie("cardHoarder", $row['ID'], $expire, '/');
```

Checking if a user is logged in uses the following code

```
$loggedIn = (isset($_COOKIE['cardHoarder'])) ? '1' : '0';
```

This is included in the config file which is included on all the php files on the site. Its being treated as though the cookies aren’t set even though I can see them.

[image]

Can also see the issue on the following page - [link here](http://card-hoarder.com) - If you browse to this page, select the randomiser link in the header, select another link then go back to the randomiser, the same images show

No errors are being reported on the site. Can anyone point me towards what else to look at

Comment: You should provide source code, to see what is wrong with your session handling or what other problem causes  it

Comment: Its done through cookies, I've added the code that sets them then checks them

Comment: it is still hard to tell what you are doing at all, to change the wensite you must use javascipt or ajax, but i don't see how the comunication is done,

Comment: That was just an example, its happening on any page where there are calls to the database. Added the javascript code and accosted php function it calls. Selecting the swap more coupons link in the function should take you back to the original page, which it does but it doesn't reload the sql query to get the new list

Comment: It should run the query again to get an updated set of coupons

Comment: page should be refreshed to get new cookie values i think

Comment: get the same issue even if its the first time visiting a page since logging in

Comment: Regarding the caching issues: are you setting the Cache-Control header in your php code? If no then try setting it to 'no-store'

Comment: I have the following in the html header, nothing on php.     <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />

Comment: I would suggest setting the Cache-Control header and also using cache-busting for the urls/links you don't want cached (https://www.keycdn.com/support/what-is-cache-busting)

Comment: cache-busting isn't really going to help as the content comes from the database and is random in some cases. I've set the cache control header on php and this seems to have resolved it. I've never had to do this in the past, I wonder if something has changed on my host